# svn: Is there a way to avoid extraneous re-loading of externals?

Tags: svn, externals

When I do an `svn update`, it reloads all the externals, even though I've given them all an explicit revision in `svn:externals`, and I haven't modified this property or the files in question.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be quite simply:

```
svn update --ignore-externals
```

`svn help update` has additional information on other parameters.

Comment: Hmmm, that's a workaround solution, but it (a) requires an extra parameter, and (b) requires the use of the command line (I'm working w/ a team that uses TortoiseSVN). Isn't there a way to make SVN be smarter about when it re-fetches externals? (e.g. on svn:externals property change)

Comment: @Jason S: TortoiseSVN has the same feature. If you use the "Update to Revision" context menu, there is a "Omit Externals" checkbox.